# Using Functions in C like Instance Methods of Classes in OOPs

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-structures, parameters

I made Some Data Structures in C, With Some Function Pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Defining Sort Type of An Array To Efficient Uses.
#define __Sort_Type_Unsorted__ 0
#define __Sort_Type_Ascending__ 1
#define __Sort_Type_Descending__ 2

// Defining Some Error Massages
#define __D_I_A_S__ERROR_01__ "\nDynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 01 |-<%s> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array is Deleted!!!", __FUNCTION__
#define __D_I_A_S__ERROR_02__ "\nDynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 02 |-<%s> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array Index Out of Range!!!", __FUNCTION__

typedef struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure
{
    int __Size__;                     //#### Size of Array
    int *__Base_Address__;            //#### Address of 0th Index of The Array
    unsigned short int __Sort_Type__; //#### Type of Array. Possible Values: 0. Unsorted, 1. Sorted in Ascending Order, 2. Sorted In Descending Order.

    void (*repr)(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *structure);
    void (*delete)(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *structure);
    int (*pop)(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *structure, int index);
    int (*search)(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *structure, int element);
    void (*append)(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *structure, int element);
    void (*remove)(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *structure, int element);
    void (*insert)(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *structure, int index, int element);

} int_Array;

void __D_I_A_S_Insert__(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *arr, int index, int element)
{
    if ((arr->__Sort_Type__) == __Sort_Type_Ascending__)
    {
        if (((arr->__Base_Address__)[index - 1] > element) || (element < (arr->__Base_Address__)[index]))
        {
            arr->__Sort_Type__ = __Sort_Type_Unsorted__;
        }
    }
    else if ((arr->__Sort_Type__) == __Sort_Type_Descending__)
    {
        if (((arr->__Base_Address__)[index - 1] < element) || (element > (arr->__Base_Address__)[index]))
        {
            arr->__Sort_Type__ = __Sort_Type_Unsorted__;
        }
    }
    if ((arr->__Size__) == -1)
    {
        printf(__D_I_A_S__ERROR_01__);
    }
    else if ((arr->__Size__) <= index)
    {
        printf(__D_I_A_S__ERROR_02__);
    }
    else
    {
        int temp_Array[(arr->__Size__)];

        for (int i = 0; i < (arr->__Size__); i++)
        {
            temp_Array[i] = (arr->__Base_Address__)[i];
        }

        (arr->__Size__)++;
        (arr->__Base_Address__) = (int *)realloc((arr->__Base_Address__), ((arr->__Size__) * sizeof(int)));

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            (arr->__Base_Address__)[i] = temp_Array[i];
        }
        (arr->__Base_Address__)[index] = element;

        for (int i = (index + 1); i < (arr->__Size__); i++)
        {
            (arr->__Base_Address__)[i] = temp_Array[i - 1];
        }
    }
}

void __D_I_A_S_Remove__(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *arr, int element)
{
    if ((arr->__Size__) == -1)
    {
        printf(__D_I_A_S__ERROR_01__);
    }
    else
    {
        int first_Occurrence_Index = arr->search(arr, element);

        int temp_Array[(arr->__Size__) - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < first_Occurrence_Index; i++)
        {
            temp_Array[i] = (arr->__Base_Address__)[i];
        }

        for (int i = (first_Occurrence_Index) + 1; i < (arr->__Size__); i++)
        {
            temp_Array[i - 1] = (arr->__Base_Address__)[i];
        }

        (arr->__Base_Address__) = (int *)realloc((arr->__Base_Address__), ((arr->__Size__) - 1) * sizeof(int));

        (arr->__Size__)--;
        for (int i = 0; i < (arr->__Size__); i++)
        {
            (arr->__Base_Address__)[i] = temp_Array[i];
        }
    }
}

void __D_I_A_S_Append__(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *arr, int element)
{
    if ((arr->__Sort_Type__) == __Sort_Type_Ascending__)
    {
        if ((arr->__Base_Address__)[(arr->__Size__)] > element)
        {
            arr->__Sort_Type__ = __Sort_Type_Unsorted__;
        }
    }
    else if ((arr->__Sort_Type__) == __Sort_Type_Descending__)
    {
        if ((arr->__Base_Address__)[(arr->__Size__)] < element)
        {
            arr->__Sort_Type__ = __Sort_Type_Unsorted__;
        }
    }
    if ((arr->__Size__) == -1)
    {
        printf(__D_I_A_S__ERROR_01__);
    }
    else if ((arr->__Size__) == 0)
    {
        (arr->__Size__) = 1;
        (arr->__Base_Address__)[0] = element;
    }
    else
    {
        int temp_Array[(arr->__Size__)];

        for (int i = 0; i < (arr->__Size__); i++)
        {
            temp_Array[i] = (arr->__Base_Address__)[i];
        }

        (arr->__Size__)++;
        (arr->__Base_Address__) = (int *)realloc((arr->__Base_Address__), ((arr->__Size__) * sizeof(int)));

        for (int i = 0; i < (arr->__Size__) - 1; i++)
        {
            (arr->__Base_Address__)[i] = temp_Array[i];
        }
        (arr->__Base_Address__)[(arr->__Size__) - 1] = element;
    }
}

int __D_I_A_S_Search__(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *arr, int element)
{
    if (arr->__Size__ == -1)
    {
        printf(__D_I_A_S__ERROR_01__);
    }
    else
    {
        if ((arr->__Sort_Type__) == __Sort_Type_Unsorted__)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (arr->__Size__); i++)
            {
                if ((arr->__Base_Address__)[i] == element)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ((arr->__Sort_Type__) == __Sort_Type_Ascending__)
        {
            int middle_Index, Left_Most_Searching_Index, Right_Most_Searching_Index;
            Left_Most_Searching_Index = 0;
            Right_Most_Searching_Index = (arr->__Size__) - 1;

            while (Left_Most_Searching_Index <= Right_Most_Searching_Index)
            {
                middle_Index = (Left_Most_Searching_Index + Right_Most_Searching_Index) / 2;

                if ((arr->__Base_Address__)[middle_Index] == element)
                {
                    return middle_Index;
                }
                else if ((arr->__Base_Address__)[middle_Index] < element)
                {
                    Left_Most_Searching_Index = middle_Index + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Right_Most_Searching_Index = middle_Index - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ((arr->__Sort_Type__) == __Sort_Type_Descending__)
        {
            int middle_Index, Left_Most_Searching_Index, Right_Most_Searching_Index;
            Left_Most_Searching_Index = 0;
            Right_Most_Searching_Index = (arr->__Size__) - 1;

            while (Left_Most_Searching_Index <= Right_Most_Searching_Index)
            {
                middle_Index = (Left_Most_Searching_Index + Right_Most_Searching_Index) / 2;

                if ((arr->__Base_Address__)[middle_Index] == element)
                {
                    return middle_Index;
                }
                else if ((arr->__Base_Address__)[middle_Index] > element)
                {
                    Left_Most_Searching_Index = middle_Index + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Right_Most_Searching_Index = middle_Index - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int __D_I_A_S_Pop__(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *arr, int index)
{
    if ((arr->__Size__) == -1)
    {
        printf(__D_I_A_S__ERROR_01__);
        return -1;
    }
    else if ((arr->__Size__) <= index)
    {
        printf(__D_I_A_S__ERROR_02__);
    }
    else
    {
        int popped_Element = (arr->__Base_Address__)[index];

        int temp_Array[(arr->__Size__) - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            temp_Array[i] = (arr->__Base_Address__)[i];
        }

        for (int i = index + 1; i < (arr->__Size__); i++)
        {
            temp_Array[i - 1] = (arr->__Base_Address__)[i];
        }

        (arr->__Base_Address__) = (int *)realloc((arr->__Base_Address__), ((arr->__Size__) - 1) * sizeof(int));

        (arr->__Size__)--;
        for (int i = 0; i < (arr->__Size__); i++)
        {
            (arr->__Base_Address__)[i] = temp_Array[i];
        }
        return popped_Element;
    }
}

void __D_I_A_S_Represent__(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *arr)
{
    if ((arr->__Size__) == -1)
    {
        printf(__D_I_A_S__ERROR_01__);
    }
    else if (arr->__Size__ == 0)
    {
        printf("\nDynamic Integer Array: {}.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n{%d", arr->__Base_Address__[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < (arr->__Size__); i++)
        {
            printf(", %d", (arr->__Base_Address__)[i]);
        }
        printf("}.");
    }
}

void __D_I_A_S_Delete__(struct Dynamic_Integer_Array_Structure *arr)
{
    if (arr->__Size__ == -1)
    {
        printf(__D_I_A_S__ERROR_01__);
        printf(" Already!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        (arr->__Size__) = -1;
        free(arr->__Base_Address__);
    }
}

void __D_I_A_S_Initialize__(int_Array *new_Array)
{
    new_Array->__Size__ = 0;
    new_Array->__Sort_Type__ = __Sort_Type_Unsorted__;
    (new_Array->__Base_Address__) = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    // Functions Declaration...
    (new_Array->pop) = __D_I_A_S_Pop__;
    (new_Array->repr) = __D_I_A_S_Represent__;
    (new_Array->delete) = __D_I_A_S_Delete__;
    (new_Array->search) = __D_I_A_S_Search__;
    (new_Array->append) = __D_I_A_S_Append__;
    (new_Array->remove) = __D_I_A_S_Remove__;
    (new_Array->insert) = __D_I_A_S_Insert__;
}

#define int_Array_init __D_I_A_S_Initialize__
```

So I can Make an Instance of The Structure and Reference To Its Methods.

```
    int_Array a;
    int_Array_init(&a);
    a.append(&a, 6);
    a.append(&a, 5);
    a.append(&a, 4);
    a.append(&a, 3);
    a.append(&a, 2);
    a.append(&a, 1);
    a.repr(&a);
    printf("\nAfter Removal");
    a.remove(&a, 3);
    a.repr(&a);
    printf("\nAfter Popping");
    a.pop(&a, 40);
    a.repr(&a);
    printf("\nElement Found At Index %d In The Array.", a.search(&a, 3));
    printf("\nSort Type Of The Array: %d", a.__Sort_Type__);
    a.repr(&a);
    a.delete(&a);
    a.repr(&a);
    a.append(&a, 1);
    a.insert(&a, 1, 1);
    a.pop(&a, 1);
    a.remove(&a, 1);
    a.search(&a, 1);
    a.delete(&a);
    printf("\nDone!!!");
```

Output :::

```
{6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}.
After Removal
{6, 5, 4, 2, 1}.
After Popping
Dynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 02 |-<__D_I_A_S_Pop__> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array Index Out of Range!!!
{6, 5, 4, 2, 1}.
Element Found At Index -1 In The Array.
Sort Type Of The Array: 0
{6, 5, 4, 2, 1}.
Dynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 01 |-<__D_I_A_S_Represent__> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array is Deleted!!!Dynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 01 |-<__D_I_A_S_Append__> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array is Deleted!!!   
Dynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 01 |-<__D_I_A_S_Insert__> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array is Deleted!!!   
Dynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 01 |-<__D_I_A_S_Pop__> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array is Deleted!!!      
Dynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 01 |-<__D_I_A_S_Remove__> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array is Deleted!!!   
Dynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 01 |-<__D_I_A_S_Search__> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array is Deleted!!!   
Dynamic Integer Array:-| ERROR 01 |-<__D_I_A_S_Delete__> Operation Can't Be Performed, Because Array is Deleted!!! Already!!!
Done!!!
```

Is There Any Way To Avoid Passing Address of Instance every time.
Is That Possible That The Below Code Will Produce the Same Output As the Above.
something like :::

```
 int_Array a;
    int_Array_init(&a);
    a.append(6);
    a.append(5);
    a.append(4);
    a.append(3);
    a.append(2);
    a.append(1);
    a.repr();
    printf("\nAfter Removal");
    a.remove(3);
    a.repr();
    printf("\nAfter Popping");
    a.pop(40);
    a.repr();
    printf("\nElement Found At Index %d In The Array.", a.search(3));
    printf("\nSort Type Of The Array: %d", a.__Sort_Type__);
    a.repr();
    a.delete();
    a.repr();
    a.append(1);
    a.insert(1, 1);
    a.pop(1);
    a.remove(1);
    a.search(1);
    a.delete();
    printf("\nDone!!!");
```

Please Tell The Solution That You Know About To Solve The Problem.

Comment: You Kind Of Need To Pass It Because C Doesn't Have An Implicit `this` Parameter Like Say C++.

Comment: Identifiers with that many `_`, especially at the start, are rarely a good idea. I recommend to have your thorough reasoning why they are used ready. If you do not have a compelling reason better don't. They are largely reserved, but not for you.

Comment: "Is That Possible That The Below Code Will Produce the Same Output As the Above. something ..." A whole sentence (actualy a question without a "?") capitalised for no apparent reason and then you start the next one lower case? I'd also like to know the reason for that. (I realise that there are actually a few "the" in there... But that does not really change it.)

Answer (score 1):

While you successfully go against several established practices in your code (probably to your own future disadvantage) and in your prose (same); I hazard the answer:

> You Kind Of Need To Pass It Because C Doesn't Have An Implicit `this` Parameter Like Say C++.

Which is of course verbatim the comment by Shawn.